# Simple way to UPDATE rows with auto incrementing value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have to set a value as 74 and increment each row by 1.

```
+----------+--------+-----------+
| p_id     | name   | value     |
+----------+--------+-----------+
|        1 | Ben    |         0 |
|        2 | Luka   |         0 |
|        3 | Frank  |         0 |
|        4 | Divya  |         0 |
+----------+--------+-----------+
```

I need to update the `value` fields as below

```
+----------+--------+-----------+
| p_id     | name   | value     |
+----------+--------+-----------+
|        1 | Ben    |        74 |
|        2 | Luka   |        75 |
|        3 | Frank  |        76 |
|        4 | Divya  |        77 |
+----------+--------+-----------+
```

I tried writing procedure but **it was not working in my DB management app - DBeaver**.

Is there any other way to get this output?

**Update 1** - My procedure which didn't DBeaver work is given below ([source](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-loop.aspx))

```
DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_mysql_while_loop$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE test_mysql_while_loop()
 BEGIN
 DECLARE x  INT;

 SET x = 74;

 WHILE x  <= 78 DO
 SET  x = x + 1; 
 END WHILE;

 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: 'but it was not working' - what does that mean , did it fail to syntax or did it not produce the desired result, Can you add the procedure to the question.

Comment: @P.Salmon Added the procedure.

Comment: You can use `cursor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can Reset the @i value using the select statement.

```
 SELECT @i:=74;
```

As with the SELECT query above, we'll update ordering by name:

```
UPDATE Mytable SET value = @i:=@i+1 ORDER BY name;
```

And result "SELECT * FROM Mytable ORDER BY name"

```
+----------+--------+-----------+
| p_id     | name   | value     |
+----------+--------+-----------+
|        1 | Ben    |        74 |
|        2 | Luka   |        75 |
|        3 | Frank  |        76 |
|        4 | Divya  |        77 |
+----------+--------+-----------+
```

*Source - [Link](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/autoincrement-value-mysql/)*

Answer (score 8):

```
select @i := 73;
update your_table set value = (select @i := @i + 1) 
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: You might need `order by p_id`, As per [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) *If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the rows are updated in the order that is specified*

Comment: Thanks @MKhalidJunaid

Answer (score 2):

According to your quesiton,I think a simple `UPDATE` will work if `p_id` is the primary key and can auto increment

```
UPDATE yourtable SET value = p_id + 73
```

For your procedure,you need to use `CURSOR`

```
DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_mysql_while_loop$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE test_mysql_while_loop()
 BEGIN
     DECLARE x  INT;
     DECLARRE t_id INT;

     DECLARE curs_update CURSOR FOR  SELECT p_id FROM yourtable ORDER BY p_id;
     DECLARE continue HANDLER for not found set done = true;

     OPEN curs_update;
         read_loop:loop
        IF done THEN
            leave read_loop;  
        END IF;
        fetch curs_update into t_id;
        UPDATE yourtable SET value = x WHERE p_id=t_id;
        SET  x = x + 1; 
         END loop;
     CLOSE curs_update;        

 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: If `p_id` is sequential then its fine, If not then you would need to generate a number

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid yeah,but according to the OP's question,`p_id` seems to be the primary key with an auto increment

Comment: Yes it seems like it is PK, but what if there are gaps like rows deleted from table and pks are 1,2,4,5,6,9

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Agree with you and I have add another solution use `cursor`,if it do not work then I will delete my answer,thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem when doing this in a procedure is deciding which row to update. You could do this by selecting the min row where the value = 0. for example

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t( p_id int, name varchar(10), value  int);
insert into t values
(        1 , 'ben'  ,           0), 
(        2 , 'Luka' ,           0), 
(        3 , 'Frank',           0), 
(        4 , 'Divya',           0); 

drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
create procedure p()
begin
     DECLARE x  INT;
     SET x = 74;

    WHILE x  <= 78 DO 
        update t set value = x where p_id = (select minid from(select min(P_id) minid from t where value = 0) s) ;
    SET  x = x + 1; 
    END WHILE;

end $$

delimiter ;
call p();

select * from t;

+------+-------+-------+
| p_id | name  | value |
+------+-------+-------+
|    1 | ben   |    74 |
|    2 | Luka  |    75 |
|    3 | Frank |    76 |
|    4 | Divya |    77 |
+------+-------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

**To have an auto incrementing value, first assign a variable like so:**

```
SELECT @i:=73;
```

This can now be incremented in the SELECT query like so:

```
UPDATE Tablename SET somevalue = @i:=@i+1 ORDER BY name;
```

To check :

```
 SELECT * FROM Tablename ORDER BY name
```